# How to set a cron expression of cron job from controller in Grails

Tags: grails, cron, quartz-scheduler

I want to get a cron expression from a user through .gsp and want to set it as new cron expression of Dynamic Job from controller. Intially my cron expression was like "0 1 0 * * ?" but now want to change it to.. say

```
String cronExpression="0 2 0 * * ?"  // in the controller

// creates cron trigger;

DynamicJob.schedule(String cronExpression, Map params?)
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this maybe:

```
trigger.cronExpression = params.cronexpression
quartzScheduler.rescheduleJob(new TriggerKey(params.triggerName, params.triggerGroup), trigger)
```

For more context see [this controller in Quartz Monitor plugin](https://github.com/jamescookie/quartz-monitor/blob/master/grails-app/controllers/grails/plugins/quartz/QuartzController.groovy) or just use the [plugin itself](https://grails.org/plugin/quartz-monitor).